# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 - TextInput value

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, kivy, kivy-language

I have recently started learning Kivy and have encountered a weird error when handling text / numbers entered in a TextInput box.

The Kivy Code looks like this:

```
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                text: 'No. of buttons:'
                markup: True
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            CustomTextInput:
                id: textinput_num
                max_characters: 2
                multiline: False
                input_filter: 'int'
```

The relevant Python code looks like this:

```
class DropDownScreen(Screen):
    def add_dd_values(self):
        dd_input = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('dd_screen').ids.textinput_num.text
        print("TextInputBox: ", dd_input, "\n")
        print("Length: ",len(dd_input))
        print(int(dd_input)+1)
```

I have referenced the value of the text input box as follows:

```
dd_input = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('dd_screen').ids.textinput_num.text
```

Here, textinput_num is the id of the relevant text input box. I am able to print the value of the text input box and also check the length of the string. Note: I have used the input_filter: 'int' statement to allow only numbers in the text input box. I understand that dd_input shall receive a string value. So, I tried to convert it into an integer value and perform a numerical operation.

However, I get the following error: **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:**

I looked up in Google and it seems that this is an issue with the data type being handled.

Can you please help me understand what is going wrong here? What is the right way to access and read numerical values from a text input box?

The weirdest part is that this error is intermittent in nature for the same piece of code. Sometimes it returns the error and some times it does not.

Comment: You omitted the most interesting part of the error message: *What* is an invalid literal for int() with base 10?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am sorry for the miss. I entered 11 or 12 as an input.

Comment: Please show the exact and complete error message you get in this case.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I thought I was entering 11 or 12 but a re-check of the issue pointed out the obvious error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Its a null or empty string. Sorry for having asked such a foolish question. I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the error is "intermittent in nature". I may be wrong but I think this is what is happening. You are getting an exception/error when the textinput field is blank/empty. Essentially, this means the value of dd_input is null or it points to an empty string, which cannot be converted to an integer. Hence, the error.

Add a condition to handle the exception and see what happens:

```
if dd_input == '':
            dd_input="0"
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks a ton. This was such a silly mistake.